# Access (and fill) different rows in array

Tags: r

Let's say I have a 3-dimensional array:

```
a <- array(dim = c(3, 2, 3))
```

and a vector with indices for the 1st dimension:

```
ind <- c(1,2,3)
```

Now I want to put a number (e.g. 1) into the rows (ind) across 2nd and 2rd dimension.

```
a[ind,,] <- matrix(1, ncol = 2, nrow = length(ind))
```

clearly does not work! A loop would work, however is there a better solution?

The result should be:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    1    1
[3,]   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
[3,]    1    1
```

Comment: Your `ind` has repeats, which we might be able to get to work, but to me lends to a possible logical flaw. I recognize you're trying to provide a simple reproducible sample (which could be done with much smaller dimensions), so perhaps it's just contrived.

Comment: OK (very treu) let me edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mapply`.

```
mapply(function(x, y) {a[x,,y] <<- 1;a}, ind, ind)
a
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]   NA   NA
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]    1    1
```

Or, for this specific case where `x` and `y` is the same, just:

```
sapply(ind, function(x) {a[x,,x] <<- 1;a})
```

*Note:* If you find the console output unnecessary wrap an  `invisible()` around the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that replaces everything in one step. It takes advantage of `[`'s operations when its argument is a matrix, each column indexing on a dimension of the array.

To confirm that it is putting values where we intend, I'll modify the replacement matrix to be `1:6`.

```r
# original data
a <- array(dim = c(3, 2, 3))
# the replacement matrix
r <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, nrow = length(ind))

# this will be what we index `a` on
m <- expand.grid(ind, seq_len(dim(a)[2]))
m$Var3 <- m$Var1 # repeat `ind` in the third dimension
m
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    2    1    2
# 3    3    1    3
# 4    1    2    1
# 5    2    2    2
# 6    3    2    3
```

And the replacement:

```r
a[as.matrix(m)] <- r
a
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]   NA   NA
# , , 3
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA
# [3,]    3    6
```